# Ideals in a local domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an commutative integral domain, which is not a field, and which has a unique maximal ideal $M$.

Of course all the proper ideals of $R$ are lying in $M$.

But, if we consider the powers of $M$: $M, M^2,M^3,\ldots$, then, is it necessary that any (non-zero proper) ideal of $R$  is sandwiched between two powers of $M$? If it is so, can the two powers of $M$ be consecutive powers?

---

I do not have any idea of the **basic** literature of these things, and I do not get it in basic algebra texts. One may suggest a reference for it. Also, if the results are true for commutative rings, one may state it.

Comment: This is not true. The ideal generated by $X$ (rather $X/1$) in the localization of $k[X,Y]$ at $(X,Y)$ does not contain any pure power of $Y$, and hence no power of $M$. In a DVR the statement is true since the ideals are precisely the powers of the unique maximal ideal.